# DBL_EPSILON issue in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode5, xctest

I am using this -

`#define IS_IPHONE_5 ( fabs( ( double )[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height - ( double )568 ) < DBL_EPSILON )` macro in my project.

I have declared this macro in project's .pch file

its working when target is my project but not when I try to run test cases using xctest.

Build always getting failed with following error - 
`undeclared identifier 'DBL_EPSILON'`

I have declared this in my appName.pch and import that .pch into my text case bundle .pch

When I import `#import <float.h>`.

This resolved my issue.
My question why this import is needed in test bundle? As it is not needed in main project.

Comment: Does the project target and test target perhaps compile on the commandline?

"xcodebuild -scheme YourProject" and something like
"xcodebuild -scheme YourProjectTests".

Comment: Why not just `.height >= 568`?

Answer (score 0):

import float.h in your .pch file at the top

```
#import<float.h>

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```